# How Scalable are ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider and Profile provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, profile

I'm using SqlMembership Provider and the Profile provider in my web application.

And I wonder when will I start running to any problems with those providers.

Does any one used those providers on large websites?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a similar question a while back. You should be fine:

[ASP.NET Membership with more than 2 million users - any problem(s)??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913824/asp-net-membership-with-more-than-2-million-users-any-problems)

Answer (score 2):

I have used them on 100K user sites without any problems.