# Is it recommended to use ASP.NET user management system on high traffic website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, scalability

I am reprogramming a high traffic website in asp.net mvc. The client gets about 5 million hits a day. Would like to know if asp.net user management system is suited for this. The site contains over 500K users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only aspect of the ASP.NET membership model I have complaints about with respect to scalability is the `SqlProfileProvider`, which provides profile support in SQL server. Due to the structure of the SQL database with respect to user profiles, it is difficult to run queries aggregating profile information across the user base.

You may find it useful to review the discussion on this question: [ASP.NET Membership with more than 2 million users - any problem(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913824/asp-net-membership-with-more-than-2-million-users-any-problems)